# Internal Server Error: /undefined at the end of url for delete request

Tags: vue.js, vuex, bootstrap-vue

Getting `undefined/` at the end of url and can't seem to figure out the cause.
using vuejs, vuex and bootstrap-vue

`
    HTML:

```
     <template slot="time" slot-scope="row">
        <b-button @click="deleteTime(row.value.id)">
          Delete
        </b-button>
      </template>
```

`

method:
`

```
    deleteTime (id) {
      this.$store.dispatch('deleteTime', id)
    }
```

`

Action.vue:
`

```
async deleteTime ({ commit, state }, time) {
    commit('SET_LOADING', true)
    const id = state.route.params.pageId
    await api.deleteTime(id, time)
    commit('SET_LOADING', false)
  }
```

`

api.js:

`

```
let deleteTime = '/api/apps/:id/content/time/?id=:timeId'

    async deleteTime (id, time) {
        const url = deleteTime.replace(':id', id).replace(':timeId', time)
        return http.delete(url)
      }
```

`

I get this `http://127.0.0.0:8000/api/apps/1/content/time/?id=10undefined/` and not sure where is this undefined coming from.

Any help would be appreciated.

Update:

[image]

http.delete module:
`

```
import axios from 'axios'

const http = axios.create({
  xsrfCookieName: 'csrftoken',
  xsrfHeaderName: 'X-CSRFToken'
})

export default {
  async delete (url, id) {
    const response = await http.delete(`${url}${id}/`)
    return response
  }
}
```

`

Thanks

Comment: Place a `console.log(id)` in the method to see if the id is correct. Then in Action.vue and the api.js.

Comment: @echefede please check. I have updated the responses from method, action and api in console

Comment: Can you share your http module?

Comment: I assume you're asking for stacktrace. unfortunately i cannot paste that here since its an enterprise app. However looking in 'network' tab under 'preview' i see this output 
`ValueError at /api/apps/1/content/time/
invalid literal for int() with base 10: '10undefined/'`
Only problem here is i get undefined appended in url. but I do seem to get all required values in the url

Comment: No, I am asking about that `http.delete()` method. Are you using axios or what library? Maybe you have something in the configuration.

Comment: yes using axios. updated code in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a full url with query parameters to your axios `delete`. I think you only need to remove the `id` argument:

```
export default {
  async delete (url) {
    const response = await http.delete(`${url}`)
    return response
  }
}
```

Simply remove the `id` argument because `${id}/` evaluates to `undefined/`. You are not passing any `id` parameter at all.

### Easiest:

Simply `export http`

Comment: Thanks for your time. I made that change just recently as well.